# java dateformat illegal pattern character 'y'

Tags: java, locale, simpledateformat

We started having a weird error on production environment recently (test environments works fine).

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'y'

This is caused by the following code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance();
dateFormat.applyLocalizedPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This error is normally thrown when for example using 'Y' instead of 'y' for year. This is not the case here as you can see above. I'm not 100% sure of the locale set on the server. Linux env LANG is set to "de_DE.UTF_8", so this is probably used.

Entering the source code of SimpleDateFormat.java I found the method `translatePattern(String pattern, String from, String to)`. This throws the exception mentioned when any character in `pattern` does not exist in from. The values looks like this when debugging locally on a different computer

pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"
from = "GyMdkHmsSEDFwWahKzZ"

From the exception on the server it is apparent that the first 'y' does not exist in `from`. `from` is fetched from `formatData.getLocalPatternChars()`, which is a `DateFormatSymbols` initialized from the locale on the server.

Is there even locales available that could have formats without 'y'? This error has started occuring without any code change, and from my knowledge no change of server config.

Comment: What is the precise JVM you are running in?

Comment: java.vm.specification.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.runtime.version: 1.6.0_37-b06

Comment: And it is identical to the one running in test?

Comment: Yeah. I resolved the issue, it was about an initialization issue that normally sets a certain Locale that was not called correctly.

Comment: Your Swedish-German locale setup is uncommon and you might consider including such information in the question.  It is not uncommon to install US English versions of operating systems on such servers to avoid uncommon configurations.

Comment: I was not aware of the exact setup when I asked the question. We do have en_US set by the OS, but this is overridden in the startup script of the jvm to de_DE and then again to sv_SE in the application (which failed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the SimpleDateFormat javadoc :

> SimpleDateFormat also supports localized date and time pattern
>   strings. In these strings, the pattern letters described above may be
>   replaced with other, locale dependent, pattern letters.

In your case, the local is DE, so the localized pattern would be `jjjj-MM-tt`. `J` stands for Jahr, and `T` for Tage.

If you don't want to deal with localized pattern, just use [SimpleDateFormat.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#applyPattern%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks, I think I just found the error... We set server locale to german, but override it to swedish in an init servlet. I think the initalization might have crashed when production got restarted yesterday, and we got stuck with german locale!

Answer (score 8):

Ideally you should enforce locale of pattern, else your pattern would need to change for different locales as yyyy works for en_US, jjjj for de_DE etc. Instead specify only yyyy and locale as en_US irrespective of locale of your machine.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(format.format(new java.util.Date()));
```

As javadoc says:

> Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the given pattern and the default
>   date format symbols for the given locale. Note: This constructor may
>   not support all locales. For full coverage, use the factory methods in
>   the DateFormat class.
>
> Parameters:
>
> pattern: the pattern describing the date and time format
>
> **locale: the locale whose date format symbols should be used**

this way you don't have to worry about what local string to choose for runtime locale and enforcing specific locale once.

Comment: Yes I agree, the code I mentioned is from 2007 and not coded by me. We do enforce locale on our server, but a failing integration made the initialization crash before locale.setDefault(new Locale("sv", "SE")) was called, causing the server default of german to be used :)

Comment: If you are to maintain said code, you may want to make initialization errors fatal, so the application refuse to run.